# How to kill processes unresponsive to kill -9

Tags: linux

I am seeing processes on my SGI Altix 450 running SLES 10.1 seemingly stop running (i.e. not provide further output in their logs for hours).  At this point I want to kill the offending process so I can restart it.  Top shows that the process is in the (R) state.  Although when I attempt to kill it nothing happens.  Even when I use kill -9 it still lingers.  In this case what can I do other than restart the machine?

Comment: Are they definitely the same process id?  It's not that you're killing the process and some daemon is relaunching a process with the same name?

Answer (score 9):

It is possible that process is killed but waiting for parent to collect its return value. In that case after it is killed it would be in state 'Z' and not 'R'. In that case you should find `ppid` of process using `ps` command and kill the parent process too(If you are really sure it wont cause any problems).

The other case could be that for some reason process is restarting after being killed like tty. In that case the process id should change every time you do kill -9. See if process ID is changing every time you are try to kill it.

Comment: I believe I am trying to kill the parent process.  It's the parent process that is in the (R) state.  pstree confirms this.  The child processes are all in (Z) zombie states.  The ppid stays static, thus I don't believe it is simply restarting.

Comment: If you kill the parent process (and its parents process and so on) then init will become parent of the child processes which are in 'Z' state and collect their return value. So the best way to remove 'Z' childs whose parent is not taking their return value, is to kill parent as well so that init becomes parent of dead child processes.

Comment: This is the issue that I am having.  Sending a -9 signal via kill to the parent process is not terminating it.

Comment: Sending SIGHUP to parent is sometimes enough. You don't always have to kill the parent.

Comment: I'm sorry, SIGCHLD. (too early in the morning)

Comment: You would have to check stat of parent as well. If that is also 'Z' then look for parent of parent and so on. What is the stat of parent after you send it 'kill -9'. Not all processes will end instantly will 'kill -9'. I had this problem with DVD burning software. Sending 'kill -9' wont kill it as probably it was waiting for some input from DVD drive.

Answer (score 2):

The process is waiting on some system resource, perhaps NFS? that is not allowing it to 'let go'.  Would love to hear some solutions to this beyond mine...

reboot the box, or let the process sit around.

I wonder if you might be able to 'STOP' the process via 
kill -STOP {PID}
to prevent it from consuming more cpu.

Restarting it should be possible even with another stopped process sitting around,
but it may require a list port or shared memory segment that is still in use by the other process.

Comment: Wouldn't a process that was waiting on NFS or a some I/O function to complete be in a (D) state?  These processes are in an (R) state.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening to me sometimes when I do the `ls` command on a s3fs mount. The `ls` process won't kill even with `kill -9` until I force the unmount with `umount -l`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked dmesg yet? I've seen this after a kernel panic; the only way to recover is to reboot (preferably soon) — and then get a patched kernel.

Normal unkillable processes will be in the D state, not R.

Comment: Can anything be done about D state die hard processes other than reboot? ppid = 1